# Yii2 assetManager appendTimestamp not working properly

Tags: php, yii2

I am using `appendTimestamp` of `assetManager` component

```
'assetManager' => [
        //append time stamps to assets for cache busting
        'appendTimestamp' => true,
    ],
    'cache' => [
        'class' => 'yii\caching\FileCache',
    ],
```

It correctly adds the timestamp after each asset as shown:
`<link href="/frontend/web/assets/7b3fec74/css/arabic.css?v=1428761706" rel="stylesheet">`

However when I make changes to that CSS file, the timestamp does not update. Is this because of the FileCache?

Every time I wish to test my new changes, I currently need to clear the contents of my `web/assets` folder

*Am I required to delete the contents of the assets folder every time I wish to test my new assets?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had same problem when I used `$sourcePath` as files source in my asset bundle. I solved it buy adding `$publishOptions`. Making `'forceCopy'=>true` forces files to be published in assets folder each time:

```
class Asset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $sourcePath = '...';
    public $js = [..];
    public $css = [...];
    public $depends = [...];

    public $publishOptions = [
        'forceCopy' => true,
         //you can also make it work only in debug mode: 'forceCopy' => YII_DEBUG
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `FileCache` component you referred to - has nothing to do with the assets. It is responsible with your defined cache items :

```
Yii::$app->cache->set('key', 'value')  
Yii::$app->cache->get('key') 
...
```

So there might be a problem with your `assetManager`.

Comment: this is not an answer to the question, it's a comment